# Multiple times refresh token happening

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using the interceptor to refresh token there is no problem in refresh,
but I am facing the problem, I have a situation there is 2 rest api executing parallel both fails gives 401 unauthorized,so in this case 2 times I am getting the refresh token, how to avoid multiple token to get, how to sync?

Comment: check out my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77206302/11671900

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a trivial problem and depends on your codebase.

But if you don't have any specific business logic that happens after you get 401 (Unauthorized) you could solve it using this code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/alex-shpak/da1e65f52dc916716930